# TSQL Pivoting a variable length sub query

Tags: sql-server

Given Tables

```
Country
ID    Name
1     USA
2     Canada
3     Australia

Territory
ID    CountryID     Name
1     1             Michigan
2     1             Colorado
3     1             Iowa
4     2             Manitoba
5     2             Quebec
6     2             Saskatchewan
7     2             Alberta
8     3             Queensland
9     3             Victoria

SubDivisions
ID     TerritoryID   Name
1      8             Stanley
2      8             Ward
3      8             Canning
4      9             Bourke
5      9             Dalhousie
6      9             Grant
7      1             Washtenaw
8      1             Alpena
9      2             Baca
10     2             Delta
11     2             Doug
12     3             Adams
13     3             Fayette
14     3             Decatur
15     3             Hancock
16     4             Eastman
17     4             Interlake
18     5             Estrie
19     5             Montreal
20     5             Cote-Nord
21     5             Bas-Saint-Laurent
22     6             Kootenays
23     6             Okanagan
24     6             Thompson
25     7             Athabasca
26     7             MacKenzie
27     7             Saddle Hills
```

I have not been able to create a query using pivot that would produce output like this (country, territory, ):

```
Australia   Queensland    Canning            Stanley    Ward
Australia   Victoria      Bourke             Dalhousie  Grant
Canada      Alberta       Athabasca          MacKenzie  Saddle Hills
Canada      Manitoba      Eastman            Interlake
Canada      Quebec        Bas-Saint-Laurent  Cote-Nord  Estrie        Montreal
Canada      Saskatchewan  Kootenays          Okanagan   Thompson
USA         Colorado      Baca               Delta      Doug
USA         Iowa          Adams              Decatur    Fayette       Hancock
USA         Michigan      Alpena             Washtenaw`
```

Having everything ordered is a glamour, not strictly required. I know how I could do it with cursors, but having just learned of Pivot, I was hopping for a better way. Also, Pivot seems to want some sort of aggregate function, I don't need that value, but it would be easily ignored in the result set.

TIA

Also, for convenience the following SQL script will create and populate the test tables I describe:

```
Create Table Country
    (ID int, Name VarChar(50))
Go

Insert Country (ID,Name)
Values (1,'USA')
Insert Country (ID,Name)
Values (2,'Canada')
Insert Country (ID,Name)
Values (3,'Australia')
Go

Create Table Territory
    (ID int, CountryID int, Name VarChar(50))
Go

Insert Territory (ID,CountryID,Name)
Values (1,1,'Michigan')
Insert Territory (ID,CountryID,Name)
Values (2,1,'Colorado')
Insert Territory (ID,CountryID,Name)
Values (3,1,'Iowa')
Insert Territory (ID,CountryID,Name)
Values (4,2,'Manitoba')
Insert Territory (ID,CountryID,Name)
Values (5,2,'Quebec')
Insert Territory (ID,CountryID,Name)
Values (6,2,'Saskatchewan')
Insert Territory (ID,CountryID,Name)
Values (7,2,'Alberta')
Insert Territory (ID,CountryID,Name)
Values (8,3,'Queensland')
Insert Territory (ID,CountryID,Name)
Values (9,3,'Victoria')
Go

Create Table SubDivisions
    (ID int, TerritoryID int, Name VarChar(50))
Go

Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (1, 8, 'Stanley')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (2, 8, 'Ward')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (3, 8, 'Canning')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (4, 9, 'Bourke')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (5, 9, 'Dalhousie')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (6, 9, 'Grant')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (7, 1, 'Washtenaw')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (8, 1, 'Alpena')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (9, 2, 'Baca')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (10, 2, 'Delta')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (11, 2, 'Doug')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (12, 3, 'Adams')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (13, 3, 'Fayette')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (14, 3, 'Decatur')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (15, 3, 'Hancock')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (16, 4, 'Eastman')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (17, 4, 'Interlake')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (18, 5, 'Estrie')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (19, 5, 'Montreal')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (20, 5, 'Cote-Nord')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (21, 5, 'Bas-Saint-Laurent')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (22, 6, 'Kootenays')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (23, 6, 'Okanagan')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (24, 6, 'Thompson')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (25, 7, 'Athabasca')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (26, 7, 'MacKenzie')
Insert SubDivisions (ID, TerritoryID, Name)
Values (27, 7, 'Saddle Hills')
Go
```

Comment: and what would these column names be? Or, would a comma separated string value suffice?

Comment: The column names are also a glamour, so they are optional. The results of the query are for personal use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SQL (requires SQL Server 2012+)

```
select
     t.CountryName
    ,t.TerritoryName
    ,Col1 = max(Col1)
    ,Col2 = max(Col2)
    ,Col3 = max(Col3)
    ,Col4 = max(Col4)
    ,Col5 = max(Col5)
    ,Col6 = max(Col6)
    ,Col7 = max(Col7)
    ,Col8 = max(Col8)
from (
    select
         CountryName        = Country.Name
        ,TerritoryName      = Territory.Name
        ,SubDivisionsName   = SubDivisions.Name
        ,ColNo = row_number() over (partition by Country.Name,Territory.Name
                                    order by SubDivisions.Name)
    from Country
    join Territory     on Territory.CountryID       = Country.ID
    join SubDivisions  on SubDivisions.TerritoryID  = Territory.ID
) data
cross apply (values
     (CountryName, TerritoryName, 1, SubDivisionsName, '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
    ,(CountryName, TerritoryName, 2, '', SubDivisionsName, '', '', '', '', '', '')
    ,(CountryName, TerritoryName, 3, '', '', SubDivisionsName, '', '', '', '', '')
    ,(CountryName, TerritoryName, 4, '', '', '', SubDivisionsName, '', '', '', '')
    ,(CountryName, TerritoryName, 5, '', '', '', '', SubDivisionsName, '', '', '')
    ,(CountryName, TerritoryName, 6, '', '', '', '', '', SubDivisionsName, '', '')
    ,(CountryName, TerritoryName, 7, '', '', '', '', '', '', SubDivisionsName, '')
    ,(CountryName, TerritoryName, 8, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', SubDivisionsName)
) t(CountryName, TerritoryName, ColNo, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8)
where t.CountryName     = data.CountryName
  and t.TerritoryName   = data.TerritoryName
  and t.ColNo = data.ColNo
group by
     t.CountryName
    ,t.TerritoryName
order by
     t.CountryName
    ,t.TerritoryName
```

which will produce the desired output:

[image]

Note particularly the use of the [***values***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) [clause](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/01/20/use-values-clause-to-get-the-maximum-value-from-some-columns-sql-server-t-sql.aspx) in the [*cross apply*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) as well as the *cross apply* itself. *Cross apply* also comes in a flavour analogous to an Outer Join; called appropriately *outer apply*.

Comment: It would seem that pivot was invented to fulfill a purpose other than what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Nottoc: Pivot is a poor man's cross apply. ;-)  I never use pivot since I discovered cross apply.